# Alamofire request error in Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

thhis code is working fine in Swift 1.2 i.e

```
  Alamofire.request(serviceRequest).validate().responseJSON { (_, Response, json,Error) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                successHandler(responseJSON: JSON(json!))
            } else {
                failureHandler(response: response,responseError: error?.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
```

But in Swift 2.0 its show error message. Kindly help me because I am not such familiar with swift language. This code i am using with singlton class

Comment: check doc...https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Alamofire%202.0%20Migration%20Guide.md